# Compare rows in the same table using Oracle SQL based on unique combinations of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have seen a few questions on Stackoverflow that pertain to comparing rows but nothing quite like this question.  I have a table with columns similar to :

```
 - Month       (Date (01-Jan-2013)
 - Country     (Varchar2)
 - SubCustomer (Varchar2)
 - FTE         (Number) Represents a value that is manually entered by employees each month
```

We may have some data such as this..

```
 - 01-Jan-2013 USA Customer1 10
 - 01-Feb-2013 USA Customer1 15
 - 01-Mar-2013 USA Customer1 30
 - 01-Jan-2013 BRA Customer2 100
 - 01-Feb-2013 BRA Customer2 300
 - 01-Mar-2013 BRA Customer2 50
```

My goal is to compare the FTE that is entered and provide an Alert in a separate column like 'High Alert' or 'Low Alert' or 'Ok' if the FTE that is entered is +/- 2x the previous month for each Month + Country + SubCustomer.  I've been playing with different Case statements but I cannot seem to get the comparison to work from month to month.

Using the data above, Customer 1 would produce an alert of "High Alert" from Feb to Mar and Customer 2 would produce a hgh alert of Jan to Feb and a Low Alert from Feb to Mar.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve that in a trigger? 

Or you just want to retrieve Month, Country, Customer, AlertType through a select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: **INCLUDED POSSIBILITY OF NULL or ZERO**

```
WITH TABLEDATA
    AS (SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '01-Jan-2013',
                     'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                 AS MONT,
             'USA' AS COUNTRY,
             'Customer1' AS SUBCUST,
             0 AS FTE
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '01-Feb-2013',
                     'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                 AS MONT,
             'USA' AS COUNTRY,
             'Customer1' AS SUBCUST,
             15 AS FTE
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '01-Mar-2013',
                     'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                 AS MONT,
             'USA' AS COUNTRY,
             'Customer1' AS SUBCUST,
             30 AS FTE
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '01-Jan-2013',
                     'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                 AS MONT,
             'BRA' AS COUNTRY,
             'Customer2' AS SUBCUST,
             100 AS FTE
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '01-Feb-2013',
                     'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                 AS MONT,
             'BRA' AS COUNTRY,
             'Customer2' AS SUBCUST,
             300 AS FTE
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             TO_DATE ( '01-Mar-2013',
                     'DD-MON-YYYY' )
                 AS MONT,
             'BRA' AS COUNTRY,
             'Customer2' AS SUBCUST,
             50 AS FTE
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      MONT,
      COUNTRY,
      SUBCUST,
      FTE,
      ROUND ( ( FTE
             - PREVIOUS_FTE )
            / NULLIF ( PREVIOUS_FTE,
                     0 ),
            2 )
      * 100
          CHANGE_IN_PERCENT,
      CASE
          WHEN ROUND ( ( FTE
                     - PREVIOUS_FTE )
                    / NULLIF ( PREVIOUS_FTE,
                             0 ),
                    2 )
              * 100 >= 200
          THEN
              'High Alert'
          WHEN ROUND ( ( FTE
                     - PREVIOUS_FTE )
                    / NULLIF ( PREVIOUS_FTE,
                             0 ),
                    2 )
              * 100 <= 200
          THEN
              'Low Alert'
          ELSE
              'OK'
      END
          AS ALERTS
FROM
      (SELECT
            MONT,
            COUNTRY,
            SUBCUST,
            FTE,
            LAG ( FTE,
                 1 )
            OVER (PARTITION BY COUNTRY, SUBCUST ORDER BY MONT)
                PREVIOUS_FTE
       FROM
            TABLEDATA);
```

**Results:**

```
MONT        COUNTRY SUBCUST FTE CHANGE_IN_PERCENT ALERTS
1/1/2013    BRA Customer2   100                   OK
2/1/2013    BRA Customer2   300 200               High Alert
3/1/2013    BRA Customer2   50  -83               Low Alert
1/1/2013    USA Customer1   0                     OK
2/1/2013    USA Customer1   15                    OK
3/1/2013    USA Customer1   30  100               Low Alert
```

Comment: So..the problem with the second solution is we have 100s of customers..I would need the comparsions to be done dynamically without listing them out per country, customer and month.  I think I can make the first solution work though ;)  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I just recreated the table using with clause. You can just use table name instead of the WITH clause.

Comment: Ok I see now..thanks for the explanation.  I am getting this error becuase some of the data has zero for each month.  I suspect it has to do with this part of the code.  I tried to handle it in the Case when, but I it still gives the error.  Any ideas on how I can get around this?  thanks  ROUND ( ( FTE
             - PREVIOUS_FTE )
            / PREVIOUS_FTE,
            2 ) * 100 CHANGE_IN_PERCENT,
 ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
01476. 00000 -  "divisor is equal to zero"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: You never mentioned NULL possibility in your dataset. Please post your data. We can help

Comment: Posted new SQL. Try the same and revert if issue persist

Comment: realspirituals hit the nail on the head...thanks...I have already put this into production!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should use LAG / LEAD.

```
SELECT Month, Country, SubCustomer, FTE
, LAG(FTE, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Country, SubCustomer ORDER BY Month) as PrevFTE
FROM MyTable
```

You may find some good examples here:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php